# Plot count of one column versus time grouped by two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, graph, plotly

I want to create a bar graph showing count of top three Products per month grouped by Company. Please suggest a way to achieve this, preferably using plotly-express library.

```
data = [['2017-03', 'Car','Mercerdes'], ['2017-03', 'Car','Mercerdes'], ['2017-03', 'Car','BMW'],['2017-03', 'Car','Audi'],
        ['2017-03', 'Burger','KFC'], ['2022-09', 'Burger','Subway'], ['2022-09', 'Coffee','Subway'],
        ['2017-03', 'Clothes','Only'], ['2022-09', 'Coffee','KFC'], ['2022-09', 'Coffee','McD']
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Month', 'Product','Company'])
df

    Month    Product    Company
0   2017-03  Car        Mercerdes
1   2017-03  Car        Mercerdes
2   2017-03  Car        BMW
3   2017-03  Car        Audi
4   2017-03  Burger     KFC
5   2022-09  Burger     Subway
6   2022-09  Coffee     Subway
7   2017-03  Clothes    Only
8   2022-09  Coffee     KFC
9   2022-09  Coffee     McD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach of groupby done by @kjanker is perfect have the number of counts. I think later on in plotly you can use barmode=group and add the text to the bars as product yields  something similar to what you look for.

Otherwise I don't think with plotly express you can achieve to split the columns by Company and Product

```py
import plotly.express as px


data = data = df.groupby(["Month", "Company", "Product"]).size().rename("Count").reset_index()

px.bar(data, x="Month", y="Count", color="Company", 
       barmode='group', text="Product")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pandas `groupby` and `size`.

```
import plotly.express as px

data = df.groupby(["Month", "Company", "Product"]).size().rename("Count").reset_index()

month = "2017-03"

px.bar(data[data["Month"]==month], x="Product", y="Count", color="Company", title=month)
```

[image]
Note that you have to reset the index to remove the multi index (currently not supported by plotly express).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I would also like to see contents of Product column, like a bar that represents count of Cars, Coffee etc. Here, I can't see which count refers to which Product.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that what you are going for? Otherwise an example might help.

Comment: The x-axis shows Month and y-axis shows Count of Products. Now each bar represents values of Product column. Then each of those bars is further subdivided by Company. Overall, I should be able to tell what is the count of products for each company on a monthly basis.

Comment: Can you provide a drawing?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be one way to do this. It is useful to plot aggregated data (count, sum,mean etc.) when a dataframe is grouped by two columns and we want to represent both columns in the plot. Also, 'facet_col' and 'color' could be interchanged depending on desired output.

The plot doesn't look correct with dummy data but it worked with my actual data.

```
import plotly.express as px

px.bar(df_grouped, x='month', y='count', color='Company',facet_col='Product')
```

[image]